# Func A takes inputs and returns a str. Funcs B&C are supposed to use str A to create strs B&C, but instead prompt the same inputs from Func A again

Tags: python, function, input

My assignment requires 3 functions. The 1st takes several inputs and then returns a string. The 2nd and 3rd functions pull information from the 1st and return their own strings. The problem I'm having is that when I call the 2nd and 3rd functions in the main(), I'm being prompted for the inputs in the 1st function again. Otherwise, the 2nd and 3rd functions eventually produce the output I'm looking for.

I'm somewhat limited in how I can approach writing the functions due to the assignment criteria, so apologies if it's a bit roundabout. I'm pretty sure I'm missing the forest for the trees here, any help would be greatly appreciated!

```py
def get_book_info():
    input_book_title = str(input("enter book title: "))
    format_title = input_book_title.strip()
    format_title = format_title.title()
    input_book_isbn = str(input("enter book ISBN: "))
    format_isbn = input_book_isbn.strip()
    input_author_name = str(input("enter author name: "))
    format_author = input_author_name.strip()
    format_author = format_author.title()
    input_publisher = str(input("Enter publisher: "))
    format_publisher = input_publisher.strip()
    format_publisher = format_publisher.title()
    input_year_published = int(input("enter year published: "))
    input_price = float(input("enter book price: "))
    info = f"{format_title}/{format_isbn}/{format_author}/{format_publisher}/{input_year_published}/{input_price:.2f}"
    return info


def to_csv_format():
    book_info_string = get_book_info()
    book_csv = book_info_string.replace("/", ", ")
    return book_csv


def to_json_format():
    book_info_string = get_book_info()
    # find title
    separator = book_info_string.find("/")
    json_title = book_info_string[0:separator]
    book_info_string = book_info_string[separator + 1:]
    # find ISBN
    separator = book_info_string.find("/")
    json_isbn = book_info_string[0:separator]
    book_info_string = book_info_string[separator + 1:]
    # find author
    separator = book_info_string.find("/")
    json_author = book_info_string[0:separator]
    book_info_string = book_info_string[separator + 1:]
    # find publisher
    separator = book_info_string.find("/")
    json_publisher = book_info_string[0:separator]
    book_info_string = book_info_string[separator + 1:]
    # find year published
    separator = book_info_string.find("/")
    json_year = book_info_string[0:separator]
    book_info_string = book_info_string[separator + 1:]
    # find price
    json_price = book_info_string 
    book_json = f'"title":"{json_title}","isbn":"{json_isbn}",author_name":"{json_author}","publisher":"{json_publisher}","year_published:":"{json_year}","price":"{json_price}"'
    return book_json


def main():
    get_book_info()
    print("----------------")
    book_csv = to_csv_format()
    print(book_csv)
    print("----------------")
    book_json = to_json_format()
    print(book_json)
    pass


main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you call `get_book_info()` you will prompted to enter your data. You have to call it only once in the main, store the result in a variable and pass this variable to your other functions.

```
def get_book_info():
    input_book_title = str(input("enter book title: "))
    format_title = input_book_title.strip()
    format_title = format_title.title()
    input_book_isbn = str(input("enter book ISBN: "))
    format_isbn = input_book_isbn.strip()
    input_author_name = str(input("enter author name: "))
    format_author = input_author_name.strip()
    format_author = format_author.title()
    input_publisher = str(input("Enter publisher: "))
    format_publisher = input_publisher.strip()
    format_publisher = format_publisher.title()
    input_year_published = int(input("enter year published: "))
    input_price = float(input("enter book price: "))
    info = f"{format_title}/{format_isbn}/{format_author}/{format_publisher}/{input_year_published}/{input_price:.2f}"
    return info


def to_csv_format (book_info_string):
    book_csv = book_info_string.replace("/", ", ")
    return book_csv


def to_json_format (book_info_string):
    # find title
    separator = book_info_string.find("/")
    json_title = book_info_string[0:separator]
    book_info_string = book_info_string[separator + 1:]
    # find ISBN
    separator = book_info_string.find("/")
    json_isbn = book_info_string[0:separator]
    book_info_string = book_info_string[separator + 1:]
    # find author
    separator = book_info_string.find("/")
    json_author = book_info_string[0:separator]
    book_info_string = book_info_string[separator + 1:]
    # find publisher
    separator = book_info_string.find("/")
    json_publisher = book_info_string[0:separator]
    book_info_string = book_info_string[separator + 1:]
    # find year published
    separator = book_info_string.find("/")
    json_year = book_info_string[0:separator]
    book_info_string = book_info_string[separator + 1:]
    # find price
    json_price = book_info_string 
    book_json = f'"title":"{json_title}","isbn":"{json_isbn}",author_name":"{json_author}","publisher":"{json_publisher}","year_published:":"{json_year}","price":"{json_price}"'
    return book_json


def main():
    info = get_book_info()
    print("----------------")
    book_csv = to_csv_format (info)
    print(book_csv)
    print("----------------")
    book_json = to_json_format (info)
    print(book_json)
    pass


main()
```

Comment: I made the changes you suggested, and I'm still having the same issue. I'm thoroughly confused. I did have to save the result of get_book_info() using a slightly different variable name, as naming it get_book_info resulted in 'UnboundLocalError: local variable 'get_book_info' referenced before assignment'
*edit: apparently I can't paste code here, neat*

Comment: @comradeshmoo You probably didn't remove the ```get_book_info()``` call from the other functions. About the variable name you are right, you have to name it something else as the function, my fault. I updated the answer with the full code.

Comment: I ended up figuring it out, you definitely pointed me in the correct direction! `book_info_string = get_book_info()` was absolutely the culprit. Thanks so much for nudging me towards the solution, I was pulling my hair out